# I have created a netsted form and action, but keep getting a to_key error

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4, nested

I'm trying to follow along with a tutorial. I am using the same methods as a Blog Post and Blog Comment type tutorial, just trying something a little different. I keep getting an error: 
undefined method `to_key' for        #(had to remove the first <)Agentinteraction::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fa4d43ca138>

With the errors highlighted as: NoMethodError in Agents#show

```
<% form_for @qrreviews, :url => create_qrreview_agents_path do |f| %>
```

Routes:

```
 resources :agents do 
        collection do 
          post 'create_qrreview', to: 'agents#create_qrreview'
        end
    end
```

Agents Show Action:

```
 def show
     @qrreviews = Agentinteraction.where("agent_id = ?", @agent.id)
     @agentinteraction = Agentinteraction.new

  end
```

show.html.erb

```
 <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

  <%= @agent.name %>
  <%= @agent.email %>
  <%= @agent.team %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_agent_path(@agent) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', agents_path %>

QR Feedback:<br/><br/>
<%#= @comments.blog %>


<% @qrreviews.each do |qrreview| %>
  <%= qrreview.agent_id %><br>
  <%= qrreview.yes_or_no %><br>

<% end %>
<br/><br/>
<% form_for @qrreviews, :url => create_qrreview_agents_path do |f| %>
Category:
Interaction:
Act One Score:
Act Two Score: 
Act Three Score: 

Type of Interaction:

Training Needed?
Type of Training Needed?
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

> undefined method `to_key' for Agentinteraction::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fa4d43ca138

The problem is you have define `@qrreviews = Agentinteraction.where("agent_id = ?", @agent.id)` which returns a ***AR_Relation***.

Try changing

```
@qrreviews = Agentinteraction.where("agent_id = ?", @agent.id)
```

to

```
@qrreviews = Agentinteraction.where("agent_id = ?", @agent.id).first
```

Also

```
<% form_for @qrreviews, :url => create_qrreview_agents_path do |f| %>
```

should be

```
<%= form_for @qrreviews, :url => create_qrreview_agents_path do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Pavan. It still took me a good couple of seconds to realize what the missing character in the second answer. I was almost there!